# Is Rails 3 missing an error translation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my en.yml I have this:

```
en:
  errors:
    format: "%{message}"
    messages:
      blank:        "%{attribute} can't be blank"
      invalid:      "%{attribute} is invalid"
      too_short:    "%{attribute} is too short"
      too_long:     "%{attribute} is too long"
      wrong_length: "%{attribute} is the wrong length"
      taken:        "%{attribute}, {value}, is already taken"
```

And here's my User model so far:

```
    validates_presence_of       :username
    validates_uniqueness_of     :username
    validates_length_of         :username,  :within => 4..15
    validates_format_of         :username,  :with => /^\w+$/i

    validates_presence_of       :password
    validates_length_of         :password,  :within => 6..20
```

When I test random data, all error messages work great, except for the validates_uniqueness_of, which returns the default 'has already been taken'

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shouldn't it be

`taken:        "%{attribute}, %{value}, is already taken"`

with percent sign for value?
I didn't know you could access `value`, but it makes sense, otherwise that could be `username`.
I see that `taken` is the right key, but I still would try without `{value}` to see if it works.

At last or temporary fix I think you can pass a message in you model validation, something like this should work:

```
validates_uniqueness_of     :username, :mesage => "#{self.username} is already taken"
```

but of course you loose a lot of benefits.

Comment: You're welcome, if this solved your problem you should consider to tick this answer as accepted, here on the left under the zero. have fun! - and BTW what solution helped you? the `%` sign?

Comment: Yep, that was it--sorry, I didn't realize the checkbox today, I will start using it.